# If UITextField or NSString is empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

If I want to check whether a `UITextField` or `NSString` is empty, can I compare it with `NULL` or `nil`?

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the methods you suggest are foolproof. The best tests are:

```
if ([myTextField.text length] > 0) ...
```

or

```
  if ([myString length] > 0) ...
```

Comment: i tested and found comparing string length is much better. Thks for the help

Answer (score 4):

> if i want to check whether a textfield or string is empty i compare it with NULL or nil?

No.

An empty string object (a string object containing no characters) or a text-field object containing an empty string object is not the same as `nil`, which is no object at all. You need to ask the (text field's) string [how long it is](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/length), or ask it [whether it is equal to](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:) an empty string you have on hand (`@""`).

`NULL`, while also a null pointer, should be used for general pointers, not pointers to Objective-C instances (for which you have the more specific `nil`) or classes (for which you have the more specific `Nil`).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but no method other than this worked for me:

```
NSString *string = textfield.text;
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
    ....
}
```